# CakePHP relationship for Posts and Attachments

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm putting together an app in CakePHP that contains both Posts and Attachments

The tables are as follows:

```
Posts = id, title, datetime, content

Attachments = id, title, path, mime_type

Posts_Attachments = id, post_id, attachment_id
```

I'm getting a bit confused with the relationship here. So far I have done:

Post Model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Attachment');
```

and Attachment Model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Post');
```

But the relationship doesn't appear to be working as expected. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Option 1 (hasAndBelongsToMany)

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Attachment');
}

class Attachment extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Post');
}
```

#### Option 2 (Alternative hasAndBelongsToMany)

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('AttachmentsPost');
}

class Attachment extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('AttachmentsPost');
}

class AttachmentsPost extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Attachment', 'Post');
}
```

**Note**: HABTM tables should be ordered in alphabetical order, so attachments_posts. And tables should be lower case and underscored. Following convention will make your life easier.

Using Option 1 has more "auto-magic" features, but sometimes it gets in your way. Option 2 involves creating a model for the join table.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set a relation where a post have many attachements then :

Post Model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Attachment');
```

Attachment Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Post');
```

And in your database, the table called "attachments" (if you follow the conventions) should have the foreign key : post_id

Comment: Attachments can be added to other posts hence the linker table